# Connecting to Flash Debugger when my AIR app comes back from background

Tags: flash, debugging, air

I am trying to debug why my AIR ios app take a long time to load when it comes back from the background after an extended period of time.
Currently, I can only connect to the Flash debugger (the popup asks for the IP) when I launch the app for the first time.

Is it possible to debug it when it comes back from the background too? I am not getting the Flash debugger popup when I reinvoke my app from the background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. No this doesn't seem to be possible. As soon as the app goes into the background the debugging session terminates.

You could add a textfield to your app and trace or log messages to it. The messages could include what it is you are measuring.

Comment: lol. It contain a lot of expletives but essentially is the same.